# Add column to DF from matrix when column names are values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, merge

DF1:

```
ID    ATR    K       
123   A      1.25
934   B      1.5
363   C      1.2
234   B      1.4
```

DF2:

```
ATR   1.0   1.2   1.25   1.3   1.4   1.5 
A     0.03  0.2   0.46   0.96  0.16  0.22  
B     0.1   0.45  0.74   0.91  0.13  0.03
C     0.04  0.79  0.01   0.80  0.67  0.11
```

I'd like to add a new column to DF1 with the corresponding values from DF2.
The column names in DF2 are values (except 'ATR').
'NEW' contains the values where ATR and K from DF1 match ATR and the corresponding column name (=K) from DF2.
Example:

```
ID   ATR  K 
123  A    1.25
```

--> (A, 1.25) in DF2: 0.46 --> Add this to DF1 ID123 column 'NEW'

How can I create a resulting DF looking like this?

```
ID    ATR     K      NEW   
123   A       1.25   0.46
934   B       1.5    0.03
363   C       1.2    0.79
234   B       1.4    0.13
```

Comment: From your post it is unclear what is the problem as it is not clear how what exactly goes into `NEW`.

Comment: Thanks, I added an explanation and example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below should work:

***Create DataFrame***

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[123,934,363,234],
    'ATR':['A','B','C','B'],
    'K':[1.25,1.5,1.2,1.4]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
     'ATR':['A','B','C'],
    1.0:[0.03, 0.1, 0.04],
    1.2:[0.2, 0.45, 0.79],
    1.25:[0.46, 0.74, 0.01],
    1.3:[0.96, 0.91, 0.80],
    1.4:[0.16, 0.13, 0.67],
    1.5:[0.22, 0.03, 0.11]

})
```

***Modify DataFrame df2***

```
df2 = df2.set_index('ATR')
df2 = df2.unstack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0':'K', 0:'NEW'})
```

***Merge DataFrames df1 and df2***

```
newdf = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['ATR','K'], how='inner')
newdf
```

[image]

Comment: I got: 
ValueError: You are trying to merge on float64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat.  
print(df2['K'].dtypes) says object, where print(df1['K'].dtypes) says float64.

Comment: Okay. The error is correct. Both columns should have same data type when merging. It seems in `df2` the `K` values  `1.0   1.2   1.25   1.3   1.4   1.5` in your code could have 'quotes' around it that make it a string or object. For example: `"1.0"`, `"1.2"` etc. If those quotes are removed it should work. Alternatively, you could set the `df2['K'] = df2['K'].astype('float')`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution below, where `df2` is a dataframe with the index set as 'ATR',

```
df1.join(df2.stack().rename('NEW'), on=['ATR', 'K'])
```